# Can I continue answering "this" user

Tags: discussion

This  [user](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/3146/kvvaradha?tab=questions) posted nearly 20 questions (atm), I have answered many of it. I believe the user is new to elementary.

I am well aware of SE policy, if I continue answering, at one point the system treats like I am abusing the system. I don't want to be blamed. Does my *assumptions* are true?

What should I do?

Before writing this post I [have commented](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/how-can-i-remove-default-screenshot-app-from-freya#comment6072_3496) the answer.

At present there might be no issues, I am considering `in future`.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what policy you are talking about. There's no reason to not answer on-topic questions that you know (or can discover) the answer to. There's no automated system that will cause you problems. If you think the questions are too, eh hum, elementary, try putting yourself in the frame of mind of a new user of elementary. Simple questions can be useful too. This is doubly true if there aren't easy ways to find answers other than asking. Remember, part of the goal of the site is to create a corpus of handy knowledge to be discovered later via search.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment. Regarding the word _policy_, sorry, I may wrongly used the word. @JonEricson

Comment: Not quite sure what you're talking about here...

Comment: I have combined [serial voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857?s=2|0.0000#126857) with serial answering (in this case may be not _serial_ ), there are guidelines for voting, but not for answering. @RolandiXor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of marking this as "answered", yes, you can.

Comment: thanks for making this post answered :)

Comment: more clearly "If you keep voting for or against the same user, the system will reverse the votes. But there's nothing wrong with answering the same user."